# A href executed if the validation successful - JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, submit, href

I am trying to let a href work if the fields are validated, so I set an a link not populated such as:

```
     <input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
     <a type="submit" href="{% register %}" class="btn submit">
     </a>
```

In Jquery

```
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   if (validate()) {
     <!-- not sure how to submit the href here -->
   }
```

});

Btw, href is part of Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't target the button, target the form and prevent the default action inside the if:

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function(e) {    
   if (!validate()) {
     e.preventDefault();
     return;
   }
});
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/skaparate/u29ktrnh/12/) an example of form validation